# Fix Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm using `Angular CLI: 6.0.8` and I have implemented the following service below. The problem is my code editor linter keeps on displaying an error as follows :

```
[ts] Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.
any
```

The error is on the return statement that has `.map()` function:

............

```
return bills.map((bill) => new Bill(bill));
```

.................

## service

```
// imported the HttpClient to make the HTTP requests.
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Bill } from '../../models/bill'

import { Observable } from  'rxjs/Observable';

import  'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';




// Transform this TypeScript class into an injectable service.
@Injectable()
export class BillServiceProvider {
  // url: string = 'https://localhost:8000/api';
  // Hold the address of your back-end API.
  baseUrl:string = "http://localhost:8000/api/properties";
// Add, 'Http' injection in the constructor.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // console.log('Hello BillServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  // Sending a GET request to /bills
  public  getBills(): Observable<Bill[]> {
    return this.http
    .get(this.baseUrl + '/bills')
    .map(bills => {
      return bills.map((bill) => new Bill(bill));
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.error(err);
    })

  }
```

Comment: bills is not an array it's an object. you cannot use the map function on objects.

Comment: Try typing your call : `return this.http
    .get<Bill[]>(...)`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka have a look at this link especially on the - Implementing getProducts() for Getting All Products. https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-http-client/

Comment: @pmutua the least you could do is keep people updated of what you tried, and mark your question as resolved if it is resolved ...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type that is being returned, using an interface, class, etc.  In this case you need to use **`return this.http.get<Bill[]>`**

```
public  getBills(): Observable<Bill[]> {
    return this.http.get<Bill[]>(this.baseUrl + '/bills')
    .map(bills => {
      return bills.map((bill) => new Bill(bill));
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.error(err);
    })
```

Comment: The code is right but I have a hard time with the description. And this should be a comment.

Comment: Do map is required as OP has used `httpClient`?

Comment: @Jai that's what I was talking about : the description makes it unclear. He maps to create class instances, not to `json()` the answer.

Comment: does it make sense now? i was typing from mobile :P

Comment: @Sajeetharan better yes ! and I feel your pain :)

Comment: @Sajeetharan well as I said, this should be a comment !

Answer (score 0):

Starting in **version 5.5** the new way is using ["pipeable operators"](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

> myObservable
>   .pipe(map(data => data))
>      .subscribe(...);

Comment: Not related to the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
// imported the HttpClient to make the HTTP requests.
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Bill } from '../../models/bill'

import { Observable } from  'rxjs/Observable';

import  'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';

// Transform this TypeScript class into an injectable service.
@Injectable()
export class BillServiceProvider {
  // url: string = 'https://localhost:8000/api';
  // Hold the address of your back-end API.
  baseUrl:string = "http://localhost:8000/api/properties";
// Add, 'Http' injection in the constructor.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // console.log('Hello BillServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  // Sending a GET request to /bills
  public  getBills(): Observable<Bill[]> {
    return this.http
    .get(this.baseUrl + '/bills')
    .map(bills => {
      return bills.map((bill) => {
       const billObj = new Bill(bill);
       return billObj;
      });
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.error(err);
    })

  }
```